# Оптимизировать код!

Tags: php, mysql

Ребят помогите оптимизировать код!
Грузиться долго а товаров еще не так много!
Вот сам код, может примитивные ошибки наделал - буду благодарен очень!

```
<?php
$start = microtime(true);
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Kiev');

include('db_bace.php');

$connect_to_db = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_password) or die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
mysql_select_db($db_name, $connect_to_db) or die("Could not select DB: " . mysql_error());

$qrs_result = mysql_query("select * from oc_category ") or die(mysql_error());
while ($data_s = mysql_fetch_array($qrs_result)) {
    $category_id = $data_s['category_id'];
    $parent_id   = $data_s['parent_id'];

    $advx_result = mysql_query("select * from oc_category_description where (category_id = $category_id)") or die(mysql_error());
    $oc_category_description = mysql_fetch_array($advx_result);

    if ($parent_id == 0) {
        $cat_text .= ("<category id=\"$category_id\">" . $oc_category_description['name'] . "</category>");
    } else {
        $cat_text .= ("<category id=\"$category_id\" parentID=\"$parent_id\">" . $oc_category_description['name'] . "</category>");
    }
}
$qr_result = mysql_query("select * from oc_product ") or die(mysql_error());

while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($qr_result)) {
    $product_id      = $data['product_id'];
    $manufacturer_id = $data['manufacturer_id'];

    $ad_result = mysql_query("select * from oc_product_description where (product_id = $product_id)") or die(mysql_error());
    $oc_product_description = mysql_fetch_array($ad_result);

    $dad_result = mysql_query("select * from oc_product_to_category where (product_id = $product_id)") or die(mysql_error());
    while ($oc_product_to_category = mysql_fetch_array($dad_result)) {

        $oc_product_to_category2 = $oc_product_to_category['category_id'];

        $dad_result23 = mysql_query("select * from oc_category where (category_id = $oc_product_to_category2)") or die(mysql_error());
        $oc_product_description33 = mysql_fetch_array($dad_result23);

        $category_id23 = $oc_product_description33['category_id'];
        $parent_id23   = $oc_product_description33['parent_id'];

        if ($parent_id23 == 0) {
            $cat_azamat = ("$category_id23");
        } else {
            $cat_azamat = ("$parent_id23");
        }


    }

    $dads_result = mysql_query("select * from oc_url_alias where (query = 'product_id=$product_id')") or die(mysql_error());
    $oc_url_alias = mysql_fetch_array($dads_result);

    $dsdf_result = mysql_query("select * from oc_manufacturer where (manufacturer_id = $manufacturer_id)") or die(mysql_error());
    $oc_manufacturer = mysql_fetch_array($dsdf_result);

    $text .= ("<item id=\"$product_id\" available=\"true\">
                    <name>" . $oc_product_description['name'] . "</name>
                    <categoryId>$cat_azamat</categoryId>
                    <price>" . $data['price'] . "</price> 
                    <url>site.ru" . $oc_url_alias['keyword'] . "</url>
                    <picture>site.ruimage/" . $data['image'] . "</picture> 
                    <vendor>" . $oc_manufacturer['name'] . "</vendor>
                    <description>
                    " . $oc_product_description['description'] . "
                    </description>
                    <warranty>1</warranty>
                    </item>");
}

$parse_date = date("Y-m-d");
$parse_time = date("H:i");

$full_text = ("<price date=\"$parse_date $parse_time\">
                    <name>Тайтл</name>
                    <currency id=\"UAH\" rate=\"1\" plus=\"0\"/>
                    <catalog>" . $cat_text . "</catalog> 
                    <items>" . $text . "</items> 
                    </price>");
echo $full_text;
$file_name = '/var/www/***/data/www/***/parser.xml';
$w         = fopen($file_name, 'w');
fwrite($w, $full_text);
fclose($w);


mysql_close($connect_to_db);
$time = microtime(true) - $start;
printf('Скрипт выполнялся %.4F сек.', $time);

?>
```

Comment: мне читать лень, но непонятно, почему вы к одной и той таблице по нескольку раз обращаетесь

Comment: Вместо select * для начала надо использовать перечисление только нужных колонок. Далее лезете в гугл находите простейший учебник по SQL. Избавляетесь от циклов читающих одну таблицу по данным другой таблицы - преобразуете их в чуть более сложные запросы, выбирающие нужные данные сразу из нескольких таблиц (это базовый уровень SQL, можно изучить за день-два)

Answer (score 1):

Связывать данные следует средствами СУБД. Измените SQL запрос таким образом, чтобы было меньше обращений к БД. Выбирайте только нужные данные и из нескольких таблиц сразу, определяя отношения между таблицами в SQL-запросе.

Вот этот кусок кода

```
$qrs_result = mysql_query("select * from oc_category ") or die(mysql_error()); 
    while($data_s = mysql_fetch_array($qrs_result)){
            $category_id = $data_s['category_id'];
            $parent_id = $data_s['parent_id'];

            $advx_result = mysql_query("select * from oc_category_description where (category_id = $category_id)") or die(mysql_error());
            $oc_category_description = mysql_fetch_array($advx_result);

            if ($parent_id == 0) {
                $cat_text .= ("<category id=\"$category_id\">".$oc_category_description['name']."</category>");             
            } else {
                $cat_text .= ("<category id=\"$category_id\" parentID=\"$parent_id\">".$oc_category_description['name']."</category>");             
            }
    }
```

можно сократить *примерно* (писал вслепую) так:

```
$qrs_result = mysql_query("select c.category_id, c.parent_id, d.name from oc_category c, oc_category_description d where d.category_id = c.category_id") or die(mysql_error()); 
while($data_s = mysql_fetch_array($qrs_result))
    $cat_text .= "<category id=\" . $data_s['category_id'] . "\"" . ($data_s['parent_id'] > 0 ? " parentID=\"".$data_s['parent_id']."\"") . ">".$data_s['name']."</category>");
```